# Cron rsync problem

Tags: cron, rsync

I have a problem with my crontab setup for rsync. Forst here's my crontable:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
59 1    * * *   root    sudo rsync -r -o -v --progress --delete --size-only /home/dag/Musikk/ /media/dag/25019a70-1441-46dc-af5a-822545927f78/Musikk
```

It's the last line. I have KDE. I don't know if it's anything special to look after when adding lines to crontab. I have run the line in the shell many times, and it does it's job.

Can anybody give me a hint on how to get the line right for the crontab?

Comment: You running rsync as root. Why you need sudo before the rsync?

Comment: Yes. That is wrong. I don't need sudo, but what about the other commands? I copied this from my usual rsync of folders I want to backup. Can the --progress and -v make trouble as well?

Comment: Is this _your_ crontab or is it `/etc/crontab`? It looks like the latter. Why are you running backup jobs using `/etc/crontab`? That's what your user's crontab is for. Also, why do you have the `--progress` and `-v` switches in a command whose output you never see? Finally, how exactly is it failing? You haven't told us what's wrong with it. Add `2>/tmp/log` to the end of the line and let cron run it. Then, [edit] your question and include the contents of `/tmp/log`. That will show us what error (if any) is produced.

Comment: The failing is about it does not run, or it does not copy changes to det destination folder. I will do the changes to the /etc/crontab and post the contents of /tmp/log

Comment: Is it possible to run /etc/cron as at test, or must I wait until the assigned task is run (as prescrebeded in the crontab)?

Comment: I have done what you guys have recommended and it seems to work now. Thanx for good answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the command works without any issue, there shouldn't be any issue. But, if the cron is added to the crontab of root, you don't have to use "sudo". I would suggest you to switch to root ( su - root  ) and then add the cron entry to root's crontab so that you don't have to worry about the permission. If the copying does not require root permission, you can do this directly in the user's crontab without sudo

Comment: If I understand you right i just remove the sudo in the line in the crontab? I don't need root permission to copy entries the folders,

Comment: I'm sorry this answer is rather late, but anyway,
First, open your terminal and switch to root ( using sudo or using the root password ), once you're in root shell, open the crontab and add these entries, that way you don't need 'sudo' in it